# Heroku run Jar from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, heroku

I'm trying to execute a Jar file from a Javascript file to get the console output. I've pushed both files to Heroku, but when I try calling the function in the js file, I get this error:

> /bin/sh: 1: java: not found exec error: Error: Command failed: java
>   -jar -Xms1024m MongoConnector-all abaabaa
>
> [31merror[39m: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This is the code that I have:

```
const runCoreSearch = function(searchInputString) {
  const exec = require('child_process').exec;
  //child = exec('/usr/bin/java -jar ~/Applications/Mongo Connector-all.jar' + rakeInputString,
  const child = exec('java -jar -Xms1024m MongoConnector-all ' + searchInputString,
  function (error, stdout, stderr){
...
```

On their website (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files) it says to use the command "heroku deploy:", but I'm not trying to deploy a Java project, just execute the jar from a node.js project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to add the `heroku/jvm` buildpack to your app and redeploy:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm
$ git commit -m "redeploy" --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
```

This will install the `java` command into your dyno.

Answer (score 1):

I did codefinger's solution but got the following error :

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
Error : A JNI error has occured, please check you installation and try again 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0)...this java version only recognize version up to 52.0
```

To fix this,

- Create a file named system.properties in the root of your folder
- Add java.runtime.version=XX where XX is the current version of your jdk/jre
- Push the code to heroku

Documentation : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions